# How do you prove $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{2n}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{2n-1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

How do you prove that by adding two series, both convergent, one
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{2n}} $$

and the other

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{2n-1}} $$

You get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$$

Comment: Well, you can say that the first sum on the RHS counts for the even-indexed $(\ge 2)$ elements of the sequence, the other, the odd-indexed elements $(\ge 1)$, and the LHS counts for all of them combined $(\ge 1)$, so, both sides of the equation must be equal.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2007117/113214) I posted to a similar question.

Comment: no that's a completely different question.

Comment: @JoseRamirez, that’s not really correct

Comment: @MPW The terms in each series are part of a larger series given by $a_n$. The question you linked is not related to this one as it is *not* about proving convergence.

Comment: @Andy_ye, the exact same proof works for this question because the partial sums can be rearranged to give the combined partial sum in this question. Note you must show convergence, and that’s how.

Comment: @TobyMak : Yes, it *is* about convergence. That’s what the last line in the question means.

Comment: please read the title. it's not about convergence.

Comment: @MPW Why is it not correct?

Comment: @Andy_ye : The equality in the title is the statement that the series on the left is convergent.

Comment: @Andy_ye : Note too the tag “convergence-divergence”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E_N=\sum_{n=1}^Na_{2n}$, $O_N=\sum_{n=1}^Na_{2n-1}$ and $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^Na_{n}$, then:

$$S_{2N}=E_N+O_N$$
$$S_{2N-1}=E_{N-1}+O_N$$

(I.e. the sum of the first $2N$ elements of the sequence is the sum of the first $N$ odd-indexed and the first $N$ even-indexed elements; the sum of the first $2N-1$ elements of the sequence is the sum of the first $N$ odd-indexed and the first $N-1$ even-indexed elements.)

As $\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}$ and $\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}a_{2n-1}$ converge, this means that the partial sums $E_N, O_N$ converge, and let:

$$\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}=\lim_{N\to\infty}E_n=E$$
$$\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}a_{2n-1}=\lim_{N\to\infty}O_n=O$$

where $E,O\in\mathbb R$ are the two infinite series' sums.

Now, that means that:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}S_{2N}=\lim_{N\to\infty}(E_N+O_N)=\lim_{N\to\infty}E_N+\lim_{N\to\infty}O_N=E+O$$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}S_{2N-1}=\lim_{N\to\infty}(E_{N-1}+O_N)=\lim_{N\to\infty}E_{N-1}+\lim_{N\to\infty}O_N=E+O$$

Now, I suppose you know that, if for a sequence we can find out that the subsequence of odd-indexed elements and the subsequence of even-idexed elements both converge to the same value, then the whole sequence converges to the same value. Thus, $\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N=E+O$ as well, i.e. the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N$ converges to $E+O=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

We consider the series, $\sum b_n$ where, $b_n=\begin{cases} a_n, 2|n\\0,2\not | n\end{cases}$  and

$\sum c_n$ where, $c_n=\begin{cases} a_n, 2\not | n\\0,2|n\end{cases}$

Then, $\sum b_n=\sum a_{2n}$ and $\sum c_n=\sum a_{2n-1}$

We have now, $\sum b_n +\sum c_n=\sum (b_n+c_n)=\sum a_n$ which proves the result.

Answer (score 0):

$A_{2n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{2k};$

$B_{2n-1}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{2k-1};$

$c_k:=a_{2k-1}+a_{2k},$ $k=1,2,...n;$

$C_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k= B_{2n-1}+A_{2n};$

$\lim_{n}C_n=\lim_{n}(B_{2n-1}+A_{2n})=$

$\lim_{n}B_{2n-1}+\lim_{n}A_{2n}$, since both limits exist.